# ExtJS: how to get reference to an icon element (as an object) inside button?

Tags: javascript, oop, web, extjs, frontend

I have a button which contains an icon element.The button is referenced to as **obj**.

And i need to change button icon's visibility by usind .show() and .hide() methods.

Now i do it so (but i feel this is not a true way):

```
obj.getInnerItems()[0].hide();
```

It's not good because i rely on a constant component structure, if something changes in the next versions of ExtJS, the logic can be broken.

Are there better practices to solve this problem?

Comment: That doesn't seem like it would work anyway.

Comment: Can you please share code for button with icon that you are using? Which extjs version you are using?

Comment: ExtJS 6.5.2. I don't have access to the code right now.

Answer (score 0):

The better way is to use the setter method. You can use it with null to hide the icon and reset to initial config to show.

```
    var btn = Ext.create('Ext.button.Button', {
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        text: 'Test',
        icon: 'images/test.svg'
    });

    // hide icon
    btn.setIcon(null);

    // show icon
    btn.setIcon(btn.getInitialConfig('icon'));
```